# Triangle Pattern Recognition on Financial Market with Python

Tags: python, time-series

I'm working on a personal project to find Triangles on any stock in Python.
I detect the max and min points (shift(-5,+5) because if I consider only shift(-1+1) I have a lot of lines) and write lines between 2 max points and 2 min points.

I should continue with this or I should try with another method?

What I'm trying to get is this:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for insight for this same concept—so realize I don't *really* know what I'm talking about. With that in mind; you might re-consider your shift to only consider backward figures. You wouldn't have access to future

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea for this. This algorithm works on machine vision problems for finding lines of a picture from many keypoint points on a picture.

This algorithm called [Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform). follow the link for more information.

I think you can find local extremums in different scales. and base on this dots, run the Hough algorithm and find lines.
I did'nt do this but conceptually fits the problem!

If it works properly you will have strong trend lines and you can find it's accuracy by weights of this algorithm.